# mysqldump not generating USE statement

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I've got a small script which allows me to select a database, and a number of tables, then output them via `mysqldump`.

**Currently this does not include the `USE 'db_name'` statement in the output file, something which I need to be included.**

Here's an example the dump command I'm using:-

`mysqldump -u root db_name tbl_1 tbl_2 tbl_3 > output.sql`

I found [this question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/336480/make-mysqldump-output-use-statements-or-full-table-names-when-dumping-a-single-t), which describes the same issue I'm having, however the provided answer does not work for me. The `USE 'db_name'` statement is simply not written to the outputted SQL file.

Here's everything from one of my dumped SQL files, upto where it starts the `DROP`/`CREATE` table commands:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.16, for Win64 (x86)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: db_name
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.16-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

If anyone knows a solution to this, or why the solution in the [other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/336480/make-mysqldump-output-use-statements-or-full-table-names-when-dumping-a-single-t) isn't working for me, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: `... the --all-databases or --databases option because no CREATE DATABASE  statements are written unless one of those options is specified.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting the `USE db_name` manually

```
echo "USE db_name" > output.sql
mysqldump -u root db_name tbl_1 tbl_2 tbl_3 >> output.sql
```

I can see the wisdom of not mixing the `USE` command with select mysqldumping of tables. You do not want to risk creating database with the name of a production database. You also do not want the developer to become aware of not the database that will be the target. In this way, the mysqldump, in itself, can never be blamed for overwriting target tables.